# Create a warning message on a specific item

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have two page, the first page (the main page), show me all products recovered from a axios call (get). The second page, show me all warning message created for each product.

```
this.state = {
            products: [],


modalIsOpen:{
                creaAlert: false,
            },
            createAlert:{
                name: '',
                description: '',
            },

          componentDidMount() {
        axios.get(`./products.json`)
          .then(res => {this.setState({ products: res.data});
          })
      }

    actionTemplate = () => {
        return  <Button label="NEW ALERT" className="p-button-success" onClick={() => this.toggleModal('creaAlert')} />;
    }

    toggleModal = modalName => {
        this.setState(prevState => ({modalIsOpen: {...prevState.modalIsOpen,
                [modalName]: !prevState.modalIsOpen[modalName]}
        }));
    }

createAlert = () => {
    axios.post... data: this.state.createAlert
}
     render() {
            const columns = [
                {field: 'product', header: 'Product',headerStyle:"color:'blue'"},
                {body: this.actionTemplate }
            ];

    <DataTable value={this.props.products}>
                    {dynamicColumns}
                </DataTable>
```

when I click on the button, a modal opens to create the alert, but so, it does not know on which product to create the warning

how can I do that at the click of the button, the post call is made for the element corresponding to the click of the button? (for example, pass to api the product's id on main page)

Comment: Please format your code, and will be great if you can add your entire component, thanks!

Comment: you mean post call?

Comment: Ok, If I understood you correctly you want to make a post call on click of the button on which will pass `productId`. and what is `<DataTable />` is it something that you have created or it is a npm package?

Comment: PrimeReact component, on click of the buotton is triggered a modal where you can add information (and save them in this.state.createalert) and after this, another botton present into modal do the post

Comment: `actionTemplate = (rowData, column) => {
            return  <Button label="NEW ALERT" className="p-button-success" onClick={() => this.toggleModal('creaAlert',rowData)} />;
     }`

Comment: You can actually pass `rowData,column` in `actionTemplate` to your actionTemplate according to their example https://www.primefaces.org/primereact/#/datatable/templating

Comment: Yes, and after?

Comment: Is it working so far?

Comment: Nope, if i try to call in modal this.state.. for take the id, the result is: undefined

Comment: That is because we haven't set it to the state. Can you please try `console.log(rowData)` in `actionTemplate`

Comment: return all objects, i need only one, the clicked

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add your entire component? It is difficult to understand from half of the code

Answer (score 0):

In your actionTemplate you can pass the rowData and column please refer to https://www.primefaces.org/primereact/#/datatable/templating

**actionTemplate**

```
actionTemplate = (rowData, column) => {
        return  <Button label="NEW ALERT" className="p-button-success" onClick={() => this.toggleModal('creaAlert',rowData)} />;
 }
```

**toogleModal**

```
toggleModal = (modalName,rowData) => {
            console.log(rowData);
            this.setState(prevState => ({modalIsOpen: {...prevState.modalIsOpen,
                    [modalName]: !prevState.modalIsOpen[modalName]}
            }));
 }
```

Please check the complete solution in code sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/9llj5z2jop

Comment: Ok, now, how to pass, for example, "vin":"dsad231ff" to api in post call?

I pass to api:
createAlert:{
                name: '',
                description: '',
            },

Because are visible fields, while "vin" must only be stored and then be associated with the post call. 

 It mustn't be displayed or editable in the modal.

Comment: You can use do like this
`axios.post('/user', {
    ...this.state.currentObj
  })`

Comment: i can do this.stare.current.Obj.vin?

Comment: vin + this.state.createalert